# wso2, bps server active status

Tags: wso2

we use wso2 product (esb, bps, greg).
I tested bps on flow action. test subject below.

installing bps server on 32gb ram linux server.
The bps server is exposed to excessive flow. and more than 40 flows all remain active status. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: you shall provide more information, what is exactly a problem. maybe the instances should remain active according to the definition (aren't they waiting for something?) what is state of the activities inside the instances (flows)?

Comment: Now it came to my mind - if some of activities fails, the activity is failed, but the process instance (I assume it is what you call the flow) is still active.